# What is causing clicking sound after light switches off?

Tags: electrical, noise

After switching off my kitchen lights, there is a somewhat loud "click" almost exactly 7 minutes later. Infinitely reproducible, with no other discernible symptoms, and it seems to be otherwise harmless. The house is new construction, only about a year old, and the sound has been happening from the start. I originally thought it might have been coming from one of the GFCI outlets, but the outlet works fine and after listening to it a hundred times I now think the sound is actually in the wall somewhat above the outlet.

I have found a few posts online (e.g. [from a DIY forum](https://goo.gl/Zg7aWV)) but the advice seems to always be, "replace the receptacle" or "don't worry about it." I am not worried about the sound, and honestly don't really even care to stop it, I just want to know (because of naturally scientific curiosity) what causes it.

Comment: What kind of lights - incandescent, fluorescent, halogen or LED?

Comment: Fixtures are recessed cans with LED bulbs. 5 cans on the circuit.

Comment: Does it happen if you only flip the lights on for a second or two? if so, is it still 7 minutes? I'm thinking something thermal cooling down...so if not given time to heat up, it might either not happen or take less time to happen.

Comment: Agree regarding possible thermal issue. Could also be something specific to the bulbs. If the bulbs are standard 120V AC bulbs, try swapping temporarily for compact fluorescent or a different type of LED bulb if you have some around the house. If the bulbs are something different (e.g. low voltage with a transformer/rectifier somewhere) then you can't do that.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried leaving them on for 15 seconds, no click. I hadn't thought of that but they typically are on for an extended period when they are on at all.

Comment: That last experiment points to a thermal issue.  I consider thermal issues SCARY because things which are thermally active like that are either arcing, or *will be* arcing. Arcing burns down houses especially when the junction boxes are not metal. One common culprit is "back stab" connections, a rapid wiring technique used to make your house cheaper/more profitable. Screw or screw-and-clamp connections are vastly superior.  Screw-and-clamp connections exist on the $3-tier receptacles and switches, not the 50¢-tier (another factor).

Comment: I don't suppose you could tell us if the sound is coming from? The switch, inside a wall or at a particular recessed can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself since I have an answer and this has gotten quite a few views.

The answer is that the sound was thermal, but not anything dangerous. After much experimentation, I discovered that one of the cans warps ever so slightly when it gets hot and after a period of about 7 minutes this cools enough to "pop" back down as it contracts. It also doesn't happen until it hits a heat threshold that occurs after about 10 minutes. Less than 10 minutes of on time yields no pop.